# Do NetworkInterface Classes update in real time?

Tags: c#, .net

Do the properties in a System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface update in real-time? Specifically, does the "Speed" property represent the current speed, or the speed when GetAllNetworkInterfaces is called?

I don't wan't to repeatedly call GetAllNetworkInterfaces, but would like a reasonably real-time value for the properties in the NetworkInterface object.

Comment: What happens when u try it?

Comment: Speed gives you the theoretical maximum speed of the network interface (f.e. 10000000). If you want to get the current usage of an interface, use a PerformanceCounter.

Comment: Good to know, that basically answers my question. Off hand, do you know if OperationalStatus updates dynamically?